# File deletion works only for first time

Tags: java, file, jasper-reports

To resolve images in Jasper report using REPORT_FILE_RESOLVER, I am creating temp file and copying to it from inputStream.

```
      final File tempFile = File.createTempFile("aaa", ".tmp");
      IOUtils.copy(resource.getInputStream(), new FileOutputStream(tempFile));
```

After the jasper report is exported, I tried to delete temp file like below:

```
    final boolean deleteIfExists = Files.deleteIfExists(Paths.get(tempfile.getPath()));
// file.delete();
```

But file deletion is only successful for first time if I use  `Files.deleteIfExists(Paths.get(tempfile.getPath()))`

Does not success for  `file.delete()`. I am implementing web application and this function can be called so many times.... 
The latter deletion time, just showing file is used by another process ...

Don't know why...

Comment: Did you close the stream?

Comment: @AlexK you are correct. Fogot to close fileOutputStream. Pls put as an answer. Thanks you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to close the *OutputStream*.

Something like this (using the *AutoCloseable* interface and "try-with-resources" statement)

```
    final File tempFile = File.createTempFile("aaa", ".tmp");
    try (OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(tempFile)) {
        IOUtils.copy(resource.getInputStream(), outputStream);
        // do something
    }
```